# Is it possible to kill the Ceadeus with SNS?

Tags: monster-hunter-3-tri

I was only able to repel/kill the Ceadeus using the longsword. However, I much prefer to use the SNS personally. I was wondering if it was even possible to kill/repel the Ceadeus with SNS.

Thanks!
N.S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. Tested it myself and found that although it is gruelingly long, it is possible.